# Generate Booking number in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have date format like `2012-10-12`, I want to generate the booking number in the format like `HK121012` with auto increment number like

```
001, 002 then 009, 010, 011..... 099, 100, 101
```

Here, in `HK121012` means `HK` is the region, `12` is the year 10 is month and 12 is day.
How to generate the sequence like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by combining [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) & [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/str_pad). Here is a rough working example. Change the variables to suit your needs.

```
$country_code = 'HK';
$date = '2012-10-12';

for ($counter = 1; $counter <= 100; $counter++) {
  $booking_number = date('Ymd', strtotime($date)) . str_pad($counter, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
  echo $country_code . $booking_number . '<br />';
}
```

Output in this example goes up to 100 like this:

```
HK20121012001
HK20121012002
HK20121012003
HK20121012004
HK20121012005
HK20121012006
…
```